# PostGIS Raster ST_Union: how does it manage no data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to use ST_Union() function in order to create a raster image containing max values from an array of tiles:

```
SELECT ST_Union(rast,'MAX')
FROM   postgis.ndvi
WHERE  extract(doy from dtime) = doy_in
AND    extract(year from dtime) < year_in
```

The no data value of these tiles is defined, into raster table, as -3000.
The question is: how does ST_Union manage no data pixels? it skips them or it include them into calculation?

Comment: You may get a better response over at gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you for answering me, i'll take a look on gis.stackexchange